# Chrome tab manager with one specific function

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

**I'd like to find a Chrome extension that allows you to select several consecutive tabs and pop them out into a new window together.** That's pretty much the only extra tab functionality I feel I'm lacking in Chrome right now.

I looked for this and found various listicles and many tab managers of varying degrees of complexity, but none seemed to offer this feature.

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try to select them with CTRL and drag them out?

Comment: @Aganju WOW. You blew my mind. Ok, sorry for the silly question and thanks a million. This should be featured as a life hack more often.